# Node.js http server crashes with unknown IP address displayed

Tags: node.js

I am running a Node.js HTTP server, and suddenly the following message is displayed, and the server crashes:

**UPDATED ERROR LOG: (after edit)**

```
Uncaught exception in main server
{ Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 139.99.8.126:80
at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1041:20)
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1086:14)
 code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
 errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
 syscall: 'connect',
 address: '139.99.8.126',
 port: 80 }
Uncaught exception in main server
{ Error: socket hang up
at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:253:15)
at Socket.socketCloseListener (_http_client.js:285:23)
at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
at TCP._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:497:12) code: 'ECONNRESET' }
```

This is a foreign IP address not used by us.
I tried to grep into all node modules for this IP address and see nothing.
Appears to be a hacking attempt but I have no clue where to start looking.
Any help will be appreciated. I have blocked the IP address in the firewall.

Comment: Some of your third party  package having script timeout in their package.json file ,Is this your full error log?

Comment: @MohammadRaheem My core question is where is this IP address coming from? Considering that this never happened before, I am concerned. Is it an incoming request to my server or an outgoing request from some module in the server? It is the complete error log.

Comment: What's the list of modules that you're using? FWIW, it's an outgoing request.

Comment: @robertklep  Thanks a lot.. Combination or your comment and the accepted answer helped me locate the problem. See comments below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [node.js docs](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors) about errors say:

> **ETIMEDOUT (Operation timed out)**: A connect or send request failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time. Usually encountered by http or net — often a sign that a socket.end() was not properly called.

You should create a handler for errors, so your server won't crash:

```
netSv.on('error', function (error) { 

   if( error.message.code === 'ETIMEDOUT' ){
      // mail the error with some additional data to you or do something with it
   }

})
```

Comment: @daklightcode Thanks this will   fix the problem but I want to know what is causing it as I have not changed any code and this just started... no new packages were installed, for example.

Comment: The server is causing it because the connection took to much time to resolve (timed out). Take a look at the `net` module on node,js docs for `socket.setTimeout(timeout[, callback])` if you plan on extending the timeout.

Comment: Why does it crash on this IP address only? The server accepts connection but also is a client that makes connections to other servers. The key is that I have not installed any new modules. Is the error message indicative of a connection timeout or socket timeout? If socket timeout than it would mean a connection is already established.

Comment: The fact that it crashes only on that IP only may be from their server settings. Some kind of headers/bad output perhaps. You can type in the browser URL that IP, it's a `whois` website and they're pinging some ip classes. And about the 'timeouts', see my updated answer please.

Comment: Got i! We are apparently using their service to get geolocation and the license expired or some such issue... THANKS A LOT!!!!